# How to use vba code for refreshing data in an external workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a macro in my 'main' workbook to refresh the pivot table data in external workbooks (country A workbook, Country B, Country C etc.)

I used this simple code:

`Workbooks.Refresh "LOCATION of file"` however the method refresh is not recognized.

ex: `Workbooks.Open "LOCATION of file"` `->` opens the file...

Is there a simple VBA Code (1 line) to update external workbooks with file path location?

Comment: AFAIK Excel will only update workbooks that are open, unless you treat those workbooks as a Database.  You would need to have the code open each workbook individually, update the Workbook, then close/save that workbook.

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply - any chance you could elaborate on the "Database" explanation! Thank you!

Comment: From the Data Tab in Excel you can choose "From Other Sources" and then choose Excel.  If there is a table in the workbook you want data to update/push to other workbooks then from the workbook you want the data to update to you connect directly to the workbook and table or named range that has updated data.  You can then set the refresh to update automatically when the workbook receiving the data is open.  It sounds complicated but it really isnt.